# How to resolve Native linking failed Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I get a MT5201 error when trying to build my Xamarin.Forms iOS application. Please see below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have build a whole working app on Xamarin.Forms Android and this is my first time running it on the iOS side. I have having all these issues which I have no idea how to resolve. I have been searching for hours and can't seem to resolve it using suggestions I have seen.

**Addtional information**

1. I have Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds v7.47.0 installed
2. I have tried all three options in the *Linker behaviour* dropdown

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Does your iOS project contain all of the nuget packages (specific to iOS if applicable) that the Android project and shared project contain?

Comment: @PatrickGoode Yes it does :/ I have all the essential packages installed. For some reason I am getting this linking problem with the google package. When I remove the package, the app runs fine!

Comment: what is your linker set to?  sdk assemblies only?

Comment: Sometimes I've seen where you have to instantiate an instance of a class used by that library in the platform specific project, in your case FinishedLaunching, so that the linker doesn't strip it out

Comment: @PatrickGoode it is `Don't Link` but I tried all the other three and still had no luck. I'm just trying to understand if there is soemthing else I have to do after installing `Google ads` NuGet into my .iOS project? At the moment I simply install the package and reference it *within* my app where needed to display/configure ads